# Pullbacks and pushouts in the category of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

Let $\textbf{Grph}$ be the category of simple, undirected graphs without loops, together with graph homomorphisms. Note that there need not be any homomorphisms between two graphs, for instance $\textrm{Hom}(G,K_2) = \emptyset$ for all graphs $G$ with $\chi(G) > 2$.

Does $\textbf{Grph}$ have pullbacks and pushouts?

Comment: Yes. Just construct them the only way you can.

Comment: If I do it the way I do it with modules, I need to do a quotient for the pushouts, right? What do quotients in graphs look like? They're not minors (afaik).

Comment: It's more like sets than modules.

Comment: Hmmm. So your graphs are irreflexive. Then pushouts don't always exist.

Comment: Actually this category has no terminal object, right?

Comment: That's right, Martin.

Comment: @ZhenLin do you have an example of 2 graphs without pushouts?

Comment: Consider $\{ \bullet - \bullet \} \leftarrow \{ \bullet \quad \bullet \} \rightarrow \{ \bullet \}$.

Comment: Thanks @ZhenLin - can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pullbacks exist in your $\mathbf{Grph}$ but pushouts do not always exist. For example,
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\{ \bullet \quad \bullet \} @>>> \{ \bullet \} \\
@VVV \\
\{ \bullet - \bullet \}
\end{CD}$$
has no pushout – indeed, no cocone exists.